# android maps sample tutorial

Tags: java, android, eclipse

does anyone have a tutorial with sample source for google maps for android that works? i'm looking to try and make an app with map functionality and would like the source to try and compare what i have with what a working one would look like.

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've found one.
http://www.youtube.com/user/CornboyzAndroid
tutorial 29 and 30.
this guy is a very nice and helpful person.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [Google tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html)

Answer (score 1):

You may already have it installed, but if not [see here](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/installing.html) for info on how to install the Google APIs Add-On in Eclipse.

Once the Google APIs Add-On is installed, create a new Android Project. In the Build target section, make sure you select the Google APIs instead of the Android X.x in the Target Name column. Choose the API Level that matches with the android version you are targeting. Once you do this, you should be able to select the MapsDemo sample in the "Create project from existing sample" drop-down box.

Make sure you read the [Obtaining a Maps API Key](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html) article.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already gone through google's example?

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html